# How to solve dependency issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-dependencies

I am learning android studio and trying to start with a new project but I am having some dependencies issues

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download collection.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download collection.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-runtime.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-runtime.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-common.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-common.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download core-common.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download core-common.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-viewmodel.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-viewmodel.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download annotation.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download annotation.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download collection.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download collection.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-runtime.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-runtime.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-common.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-common.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download core-common.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download core-common.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-viewmodel.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-viewmodel.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download annotation.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download annotation.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download collection.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download collection.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-runtime.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-runtime.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-common.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-common.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download core-common.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download core-common.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download lifecycle-viewmodel.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download lifecycle-viewmodel.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>   
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download annotation.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0)
    <a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not download annotation.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0)">Show Details</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/ihass/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle">app</a>
```

Comment: post app.gradle

Comment: Looks like you are missing dependencies in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try below step: Disable the Gradle offline work in settings.

   Go to File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.
2. Follow the Google Build your first app link and go step by step.

   link1: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp

   link2: https://www.androidauthority.com/android-studio-tutorial-beginners-637572/

Comment: it's already offline but the issues doesn't resolve so i came up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

it can be resolved if you don't want to use the appcompat library for temporary use:
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
just remove this line.

Answer (score -1):

Try to re-install dependencies, check out the Android Get Started Page :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp
Access to Create an Android project.
In your case, you just need a good right setup. Don't bypass step at this point.